# Android как получить id виджета

Tags: android, android-widgets

Создаю приложение, которое имеет свой виджет. Виджетов на рабочий стол можно разместить несколько. Для обновления конкретного виджета нужно знать его id. Как можно получить этот id? AppWidgetManager умеет возвращать массив id всех виджетов, которые добавлены на рабочий стол.

Comment: Обычно делают обход всех виджетов по списку и обновляют их по очереди. С какой целью вы хотите выбрать и обновить один?

Comment: Каждый виджет должен работать по своим настройкам. Настройки хранятся в SharedPreference. Нажав на кнопку на виджете я должен иметь возможность открыть активити  и показать в ней настройки по данному виджету. Отсюда вопрос, как понять, при вызове активити, по какому именно виджету я нажал?